# Flex faultCode list

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a list of possible faultCode values for Flex's Fault object (mx.rpc.Fault; Flex SDK: 3.4)?

At least faultCodes for faults generated on the client side?

I'm thinking of something like the list of possible runtime errors, found at [Adobe's RTE List](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/runtimeErrors.html), but for faultCodes (such as Client.Error.MessageSend, Server.Processing, etc).

Could very well be that I just don't understand my problem well enough to do a decent search, but I've come up with nothing all day.  It may also be that there is only one or two client-side faultCode values.  Seems like it would make sense that there wouldn't be a comprehensive list of server-side faultCode values, but maybe there's a list of BlazeDS/LiveCycle faultCodes?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like the answer is pretty much "No".  I guess this makes sense, I guess, since most server-side faults would come from the server.  I figured there would be a list of standard fault types, at least, as part of BlazeDS and/or LCDS.

Here's a pretty good post about setting up exception handling in BlazeDS.  Does a good job of explaining why the answer to this question is No, as well as providing a good way of handling exceptions in BlazeDS, which would give you a custom list of fault codes.

http://www.flexpasta.com/index.php/2008/05/16/exception-handling-with-blazeds-and-flex/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help:
There is what they called Fault Event(mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent)
its properties has:

```
var event:FaultEvent = new FaultEvent();
trace (event.message);
```

Try adding this in an array so that you could have ur list.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Treby.  Thanks for the reply.  The .message property of the FaultEvent object is a string that contains the values of the .faultDetail, .faultString, and .faultCode properties of the FaultEvent's .fault object.  

What I'm looking for is an authoritative list of possible values for the .faultCode property.