# BlazeDS : what ARE those standard security fault codes?

Tags: java, apache-flex, security, spring, blazeds

I'm trying to write a Flex client that interacts with a Spring-Flex java application. I would like to catch (the flex equivalent of) SecurityExceptions and

- Display an error page if the user was trying to do something they aren't allowed to do
- Pop up a login box if the user wasn't logged in

According to the Spring-Flex docs,

> any thrown SpringSecurityException [is translated] to the proper BlazeDS
>   SecurityException.
>   The exceptions are caught and translated at the proper point in the execution chain such 
>   that it will result in the proper AMF error message being serialized and sent back to 
>   the client.
>
> [...]
>   Sending back specific AMF error messages instead causes a FaultEvent to be thrown
>   client-side that contains the **proper security fault code** that can then be reasoned
>   on and appropriate action can be taken. This behavior is equivalent to that of the
>   out-of-the-box container-based security mechanisms provided with BlazeDS, so the
>   programming model client-side remains the same.

*Very* nice.

Except I couldn't find a list of security fault codes I should handle on the client-side. The best I could come up with was a question requesting a [flex faultcode list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711548/flex-faultcode-list). Apparently there is no such list. Am I doomed ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually suggest looking at the [source code for BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/blazeds/branches/3.x/modules/core/src/java/flex/messaging/security/) for this.  I don't know of another place where it is documented.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a fault code for this kind of FaultEvent.  The best way to see how to use this is to check out the security example in [the samples](http://static.springframework.org/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch06.html) that ship with the Spring BlazeDS Integration.